# Error Running Substrate Node: Unsupported or invalid BabeApi version

Tags: substrate-node-template, babe, aura

I am trying to run a Substrate node with a custom chain specification. I used the following command to run the node:

```
  ./target/release/substrate \
  --base-path /tmp/pikamo \
  --chain ./customSpecRaw.json \
  --port 30333 \
  --ws-port 9933 \
  --rpc-port 9944 \
  --validator \                                    
  --rpc-methods Unsafe \
  --name Pikamo \
  --password-interactive
```

However, I get the following error:

> Error: Service(Client(VersionInvalid("Unsupported or invalid BabeApi version")))

Here is a snippet of my customSpec.json for the chain:

```
   "aura": {
        "authorities": [
          "5DZYfSErHB9pPMY5dJB7D3pHDCtE6FBWNg5Au2qZj6KQWncs",
          "5HiaE728v5216ADKBq9DWiBEDJiCnzQRwCLkzswMcTXHpDKq"
        ]
      },
      "grandpa": {
        "authorities": [
          [
            "5CQdpn9DbythqGsLqPf1DLsweowLxok9wM83RF8YDHtRMf1j",
            1
          ],
          [
            "5HmPZgDuuBNyPemJ4hA56Ny75KgXMnVcMpZH5wp7fbapH9Uy",
            1
          ]
        ]
      },
```

`chain_spec.rs` :

```
// Copyright (C) 2018-2022 Parity Technologies (UK) Ltd.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0-or-later WITH Classpath-exception-2.0

// This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
// it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
// the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
// (at your option) any later version.

// This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
// but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
// MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the
// GNU General Public License for more details.

// You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
// along with this program. If not, see <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

//! Substrate chain configurations.

use grandpa_primitives::AuthorityId as GrandpaId;
use kitchensink_runtime::{
    constants::currency::*, wasm_binary_unwrap, AuthorityDiscoveryConfig, BabeConfig,
    BalancesConfig, Block, CouncilConfig, DemocracyConfig, ElectionsConfig, GrandpaConfig,
    ImOnlineConfig, IndicesConfig, MaxNominations, NominationPoolsConfig, SessionConfig,
    SessionKeys, SocietyConfig, StakerStatus, StakingConfig, SudoConfig, SystemConfig,
    TechnicalCommitteeConfig,
};
use sp_core::OpaquePeerId; 
use kitchensink_runtime::NodeAuthorizationConfig;
use pallet_im_online::sr25519::AuthorityId as ImOnlineId;
use sc_chain_spec::{ChainSpecExtension, Properties};
use sc_service::ChainType;
use sc_telemetry::TelemetryEndpoints;
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use sp_authority_discovery::AuthorityId as AuthorityDiscoveryId;
use sp_consensus_babe::AuthorityId as BabeId;
use sp_core::{crypto::UncheckedInto, sr25519, Pair, Public};
use sp_runtime::{
    traits::{IdentifyAccount, Verify},
    Perbill,
};

pub use kitchensink_runtime::GenesisConfig;
pub use node_primitives::{AccountId, Balance, Signature};

type AccountPublic = <Signature as Verify>::Signer;

const STAGING_TELEMETRY_URL: &str = "wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/";

/// Node `ChainSpec` extensions.
///
/// Additional parameters for some Substrate core modules,
/// customizable from the chain spec.
#[derive(Default, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize, ChainSpecExtension)]
#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]
pub struct Extensions {
    /// Block numbers with known hashes.
    pub fork_blocks: sc_client_api::ForkBlocks<Block>,
    /// Known bad block hashes.
    pub bad_blocks: sc_client_api::BadBlocks<Block>,
    /// The light sync state extension used by the sync-state rpc.
    pub light_sync_state: sc_sync_state_rpc::LightSyncStateExtension,
}

/// Specialized `ChainSpec`.
pub type ChainSpec = sc_service::GenericChainSpec<GenesisConfig, Extensions>;
/// Flaming Fir testnet generator
pub fn flaming_fir_config() -> Result<ChainSpec, String> {
    ChainSpec::from_json_bytes(&include_bytes!("../res/flaming-fir.json")[..])
}

fn session_keys(
    grandpa: GrandpaId,
    babe: BabeId,
    im_online: ImOnlineId,
    authority_discovery: AuthorityDiscoveryId,
) -> SessionKeys {
    SessionKeys { grandpa, babe, im_online, authority_discovery }
}

fn staging_testnet_config_genesis() -> GenesisConfig {
    #[rustfmt::skip]
    // stash, controller, session-key
    // generated with secret:
    // for i in 1 2 3 4 ; do for j in stash controller; do subkey inspect "$secret"/fir/$j/$i; done; done
    //
    // and
    //
    // for i in 1 2 3 4 ; do for j in session; do subkey --ed25519 inspect "$secret"//fir//$j//$i; done; done

    let initial_authorities: Vec<(
        AccountId,
        AccountId,
        GrandpaId,
        BabeId,
        ImOnlineId,
        AuthorityDiscoveryId,
    )> = vec![
        (
            // 5Fbsd6WXDGiLTxunqeK5BATNiocfCqu9bS1yArVjCgeBLkVy
            array_bytes::hex_n_into_unchecked("9c7a2ee14e565db0c69f78c7b4cd839fbf52b607d867e9e9c5a79042898a0d12"),
            // 5EnCiV7wSHeNhjW3FSUwiJNkcc2SBkPLn5Nj93FmbLtBjQUq
            array_bytes::hex_n_into_unchecked("781ead1e2fa9ccb74b44c19d29cb2a7a4b5be3972927ae98cd3877523976a276"),
            // 5Fb9ayurnxnaXj56CjmyQLBiadfRCqUbL2VWNbbe1nZU6wiC
            array_bytes::hex2array_unchecked("9becad03e6dcac03cee07edebca5475314861492cdfc96a2144a67bbe9699332")
                .unchecked_into(),
            // 5EZaeQ8djPcq9pheJUhgerXQZt9YaHnMJpiHMRhwQeinqUW8
            array_bytes::hex2array_unchecked("6e7e4eb42cbd2e0ab4cae8708ce5509580b8c04d11f6758dbf686d50fe9f9106")
                .unchecked_into(),
            // 5EZaeQ8djPcq9pheJUhgerXQZt9YaHnMJpiHMRhwQeinqUW8
            array_bytes::hex2array_unchecked("6e7e4eb42cbd2e0ab4cae8708ce5509580b8c04d11f6758dbf686d50fe9f9106")
                .unchecked_into(),
            // 5EZaeQ8djPcq9pheJUhgerXQZt9YaHnMJpiHMRhwQeinqUW8
            array_bytes::hex2array_unchecked("6e7e4eb42cbd2e0ab4cae8708ce5509580b8c04d11f6758dbf686d50fe9f9106")
                .unchecked_into(),
        ),
        (
            // 5ERawXCzCWkjVq3xz1W5KGNtVx2VdefvZ62Bw1FEuZW4Vny2
            array_bytes::hex_n_into_unchecked("68655684472b743e456907b398d3a44c113f189e56d1bbfd55e889e295dfde78"),
            // 5Gc4vr42hH1uDZc93Nayk5G7i687bAQdHHc9unLuyeawHipF
            array_bytes::hex_n_into_unchecked("c8dc79e36b29395413399edaec3e20fcca7205fb19776ed8ddb25d6f427ec40e"),
            // 5EockCXN6YkiNCDjpqqnbcqd4ad35nU4RmA1ikM4YeRN4WcE
            array_bytes::hex2array_unchecked("7932cff431e748892fa48e10c63c17d30f80ca42e4de3921e641249cd7fa3c2f")
                .unchecked_into(),
            // 5DhLtiaQd1L1LU9jaNeeu9HJkP6eyg3BwXA7iNMzKm7qqruQ
            array_bytes::hex2array_unchecked("482dbd7297a39fa145c570552249c2ca9dd47e281f0c500c971b59c9dcdcd82e")
                .unchecked_into(),
            // 5DhLtiaQd1L1LU9jaNeeu9HJkP6eyg3BwXA7iNMzKm7qqruQ
            array_bytes::hex2array_unchecked("482dbd7297a39fa145c570552249c2ca9dd47e281f0c500c971b59c9dcdcd82e")
                .unchecked_into(),
            // 5DhLtiaQd1L1LU9jaNeeu9HJkP6eyg3BwXA7iNMzKm7qqruQ
            array_bytes::hex2array_unchecked("482dbd7297a39fa145c570552249c2ca9dd47e281f0c500c971b59c9dcdcd82e")
                .unchecked_into(),
        ),
        (
            // 5DyVtKWPidondEu8iHZgi6Ffv9yrJJ1NDNLom3X9cTDi98qp
            array_bytes::hex_n_into_unchecked("547ff0ab649283a7ae01dbc2eb73932eba2fb09075e9485ff369082a2ff38d65"),
            // 5FeD54vGVNpFX3PndHPXJ2MDakc462vBCD5mgtWRnWYCpZU9
            array_bytes::hex_n_into_unchecked("9e42241d7cd91d001773b0b616d523dd80e13c6c2cab860b1234ef1b9ffc1526"),
            // 5E1jLYfLdUQKrFrtqoKgFrRvxM3oQPMbf6DfcsrugZZ5Bn8d
            array_bytes::hex2array_unchecked("5633b70b80a6c8bb16270f82cca6d56b27ed7b76c8fd5af2986a25a4788ce440")
                .unchecked_into(),
            // 5DhKqkHRkndJu8vq7pi2Q5S3DfftWJHGxbEUNH43b46qNspH
            array_bytes::hex2array_unchecked("482a3389a6cf42d8ed83888cfd920fec738ea30f97e44699ada7323f08c3380a")
                .unchecked_into(),
            // 5DhKqkHRkndJu8vq7pi2Q5S3DfftWJHGxbEUNH43b46qNspH
            array_bytes::hex2array_unchecked("482a3389a6cf42d8ed83888cfd920fec738ea30f97e44699ada7323f08c3380a")
                .unchecked_into(),
            // 5DhKqkHRkndJu8vq7pi2Q5S3DfftWJHGxbEUNH43b46qNspH
            array_bytes::hex2array_unchecked("482a3389a6cf42d8ed83888cfd920fec738ea30f97e44699ada7323f08c3380a")
                .unchecked_into(),
        ),
        (
            // 5HYZnKWe5FVZQ33ZRJK1rG3WaLMztxWrrNDb1JRwaHHVWyP9
            array_bytes::hex_n_into_unchecked("f26cdb14b5aec7b2789fd5ca80f979cef3761897ae1f37ffb3e154cbcc1c2663"),
            // 5EPQdAQ39WQNLCRjWsCk5jErsCitHiY5ZmjfWzzbXDoAoYbn
            array_bytes::hex_n_into_unchecked("66bc1e5d275da50b72b15de072a2468a5ad414919ca9054d2695767cf650012f"),
            // 5DMa31Hd5u1dwoRKgC4uvqyrdK45RHv3CpwvpUC1EzuwDit4
            array_bytes::hex2array_unchecked("3919132b851ef0fd2dae42a7e734fe547af5a6b809006100f48944d7fae8e8ef")
                .unchecked_into(),
            // 5C4vDQxA8LTck2xJEy4Yg1hM9qjDt4LvTQaMo4Y8ne43aU6x
            array_bytes::hex2array_unchecked("00299981a2b92f878baaf5dbeba5c18d4e70f2a1fcd9c61b32ea18daf38f4378")
                .unchecked_into(),
            // 5C4vDQxA8LTck2xJEy4Yg1hM9qjDt4LvTQaMo4Y8ne43aU6x
            array_bytes::hex2array_unchecked("00299981a2b92f878baaf5dbeba5c18d4e70f2a1fcd9c61b32ea18daf38f4378")
                .unchecked_into(),
            // 5C4vDQxA8LTck2xJEy4Yg1hM9qjDt4LvTQaMo4Y8ne43aU6x
            array_bytes::hex2array_unchecked("00299981a2b92f878baaf5dbeba5c18d4e70f2a1fcd9c61b32ea18daf38f4378")
                .unchecked_into(),
        ),
    ];

    // generated with secret: subkey inspect "$secret"/fir
    let root_key: AccountId = array_bytes::hex_n_into_unchecked(
        // 5Ff3iXP75ruzroPWRP2FYBHWnmGGBSb63857BgnzCoXNxfPo
        "9ee5e5bdc0ec239eb164f865ecc345ce4c88e76ee002e0f7e318097347471809",
    );

    let endowed_accounts: Vec<AccountId> = vec![root_key.clone()];

    testnet_genesis(initial_authorities, vec![], root_key, Some(endowed_accounts))
}

/// Staging testnet config.
pub fn staging_testnet_config() -> ChainSpec {
    let boot_nodes = vec![];
    ChainSpec::from_genesis(
        "Staging Testnet",
        "staging_testnet",
        ChainType::Live,
        staging_testnet_config_genesis,
        boot_nodes,
        Some(
            TelemetryEndpoints::new(vec![(STAGING_TELEMETRY_URL.to_string(), 0)])
                .expect("Staging telemetry url is valid; qed"),
        ),
        None,
        None,
        None,
        Default::default(),
    )
}

/// Helper function to generate a crypto pair from seed
pub fn get_from_seed<TPublic: Public>(seed: &str) -> <TPublic::Pair as Pair>::Public {
    TPublic::Pair::from_string(&format!("//{}", seed), None)
        .expect("static values are valid; qed")
        .public()
}

/// Helper function to generate an account ID from seed
pub fn get_account_id_from_seed<TPublic: Public>(seed: &str) -> AccountId
where
    AccountPublic: From<<TPublic::Pair as Pair>::Public>,
{
    AccountPublic::from(get_from_seed::<TPublic>(seed)).into_account()
}

/// Helper function to generate stash, controller and session key from seed
pub fn authority_keys_from_seed(
    seed: &str,
) -> (AccountId, AccountId, GrandpaId, BabeId, ImOnlineId, AuthorityDiscoveryId) {
    (
        get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>(&format!("{}//stash", seed)),
        get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>(seed),
        get_from_seed::<GrandpaId>(seed),
        get_from_seed::<BabeId>(seed),
        get_from_seed::<ImOnlineId>(seed),
        get_from_seed::<AuthorityDiscoveryId>(seed),
    )
}

/// Helper function to create GenesisConfig for testing
pub fn testnet_genesis(
    initial_authorities: Vec<(
        AccountId,
        AccountId,
        GrandpaId,
        BabeId,
        ImOnlineId,
        AuthorityDiscoveryId,
    )>,
    initial_nominators: Vec<AccountId>,
    root_key: AccountId,
    endowed_accounts: Option<Vec<AccountId>>,
) -> GenesisConfig {
    let mut endowed_accounts: Vec<AccountId> = endowed_accounts.unwrap_or_else(|| {
        vec![
            get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Alice"),
            get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Bob"),
            get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Charlie"),
            get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Dave"),
            get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Eve"),
            get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Ferdie"),
            get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Alice//stash"),
            get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Bob//stash"),
            get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Charlie//stash"),
            get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Dave//stash"),
            get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Eve//stash"),
            get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Ferdie//stash"),
        ]
    });
    // endow all authorities and nominators.
    initial_authorities
        .iter()
        .map(|x| &x.0)
        .chain(initial_nominators.iter())
        .for_each(|x| {
            if !endowed_accounts.contains(x) {
                endowed_accounts.push(x.clone())
            }
        });

    // stakers: all validators and nominators.
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let stakers = initial_authorities
        .iter()
        .map(|x| (x.0.clone(), x.1.clone(), STASH, StakerStatus::Validator))
        .chain(initial_nominators.iter().map(|x| {
            use rand::{seq::SliceRandom, Rng};
            let limit = (MaxNominations::get() as usize).min(initial_authorities.len());
            let count = rng.gen::<usize>() % limit;
            let nominations = initial_authorities
                .as_slice()
                .choose_multiple(&mut rng, count)
                .into_iter()
                .map(|choice| choice.0.clone())
                .collect::<Vec<_>>();
            (x.clone(), x.clone(), STASH, StakerStatus::Nominator(nominations))
        }))
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();

    let num_endowed_accounts = endowed_accounts.len();

    const ENDOWMENT: Balance = 10_000_000 * DOLLARS;
    const STASH: Balance = ENDOWMENT / 1000;

    GenesisConfig {
        system: SystemConfig { code: wasm_binary_unwrap().to_vec() },
        balances: BalancesConfig {
            balances: endowed_accounts.iter().cloned().map(|x| (x, ENDOWMENT)).collect(),
        },
        indices: IndicesConfig { indices: vec![] },
        session: SessionConfig {
            keys: initial_authorities
                .iter()
                .map(|x| {
                    (
                        x.0.clone(),
                        x.0.clone(),
                        session_keys(x.2.clone(), x.3.clone(), x.4.clone(), x.5.clone()),
                    )
                })
                .collect::<Vec<_>>(),
        },
        staking: StakingConfig {
            validator_count: initial_authorities.len() as u32,
            minimum_validator_count: initial_authorities.len() as u32,
            invulnerables: initial_authorities.iter().map(|x| x.0.clone()).collect(),
            slash_reward_fraction: Perbill::from_percent(10),
            stakers,
            ..Default::default()
        },
        node_authorization: NodeAuthorizationConfig {
            nodes: vec![
              (
                OpaquePeerId(bs58::decode("12D3KooWBmAwcd4PJNJvfV89HwE48nwkRmAgo8Vy3uQEyNNHBox2").into_vec().unwrap()),
                endowed_accounts[0].clone()
              ),
              (
                OpaquePeerId(bs58::decode("12D3KooWQYV9dGMFoRzNStwpXztXaBUjtPqi6aU76ZgUriHhKust").into_vec().unwrap()),
                endowed_accounts[1].clone()
              ),
            ],
          },
        democracy: DemocracyConfig::default(),
        elections: ElectionsConfig {
            members: endowed_accounts
                .iter()
                .take((num_endowed_accounts + 1) / 2)
                .cloned()
                .map(|member| (member, STASH))
                .collect(),
        },
        council: CouncilConfig::default(),
        technical_committee: TechnicalCommitteeConfig {
            members: endowed_accounts
                .iter()
                .take((num_endowed_accounts + 1) / 2)
                .cloned()
                .collect(),
            phantom: Default::default(),
        },
        sudo: SudoConfig { key: Some(root_key) },
        babe: BabeConfig {
            authorities: vec![],
            epoch_config: Some(kitchensink_runtime::BABE_GENESIS_EPOCH_CONFIG),
        },
        im_online: ImOnlineConfig { keys: vec![] },
        authority_discovery: AuthorityDiscoveryConfig { keys: vec![] },
        grandpa: GrandpaConfig { authorities: vec![] },
        technical_membership: Default::default(),
        treasury: Default::default(),
        society: SocietyConfig {
            members: endowed_accounts
                .iter()
                .take((num_endowed_accounts + 1) / 2)
                .cloned()
                .collect(),
            pot: 0,
            max_members: 999,
        },
        vesting: Default::default(),
        assets: pallet_assets::GenesisConfig {
            // This asset is used by the NIS pallet as counterpart currency.
            assets: vec![(9, get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Alice"), true, 1)],
            ..Default::default()
        },
        transaction_storage: Default::default(),
        transaction_payment: Default::default(),
        alliance: Default::default(),
        alliance_motion: Default::default(),
        nomination_pools: NominationPoolsConfig {
            min_create_bond: 10 * DOLLARS,
            min_join_bond: 1 * DOLLARS,
            ..Default::default()
        },
    }
}

fn development_config_genesis() -> GenesisConfig {
    testnet_genesis(
        vec![authority_keys_from_seed("Alice")],
        vec![],
        get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Alice"),
        None,
    )
}

/// Development config (single validator Alice)
pub fn development_config() -> ChainSpec {

    let mut props = Properties::new();
    props.insert("tokenSymbol".into(), "MCC".into()); 
    


    ChainSpec::from_genesis(
        "Development",
        "dev",
        ChainType::Development,
        development_config_genesis,
        vec![],
        None,
        None,
        None,
        Some(props),
        Default::default(),
    )
}

fn local_testnet_genesis() -> GenesisConfig {
    testnet_genesis(
        vec![authority_keys_from_seed("Alice"), authority_keys_from_seed("Bob")],
        vec![],
        get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Alice"),
        None,
    )
}

/// Local testnet config (multivalidator Alice + Bob)
pub fn local_testnet_config() -> ChainSpec {
    ChainSpec::from_genesis(
        "Local Testnet",
        "local_testnet",
        ChainType::Local,
        local_testnet_genesis,
        vec![],
        None,
        None,
        None,
        None,
        Default::default(),
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see `aura` in your generated chainspec while seeing `babe` in your `chainspec.rs` file. You can't use both in your runtime.

For some reason you are generating an incorrect chainspec. It is odd because I don't see any `aura` genesis parameters specified in your `chainspec.rs`. So I'm not sure how it ends up in your generated chainspec.